# change textfield with every keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to fill three fields with the same text but I'm only writing into the first one. This code is only working once and then it isn't (the alert is working fine constantly).

```
$( 'textarea[name="posting"]' ).on( "keyup", function() {
 var text = $('textarea[name="posting"]').val();
    $('textarea[name="posting_twitter"]').replaceWith(text);
      alert(text)
});
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `replaceWith(text)` to `val(text)`? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ccp7eopf/1/

Comment: @j08691 - you are right

Comment: try adding event.preventDefault();

Comment: j08691 is correct. When you use replaceWith(text) it is actually replacing the selected element(s) with that string rather than updating the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vxjpvzo9/):

JS:

```
$('#first').on('keyup', function() {
   $('#second').val($(this).val()); 
});
```

HTML:

```
<input id="first" type="text">
<input id="second" type="text">
```

[image: output]

All you need to do is use jQuery's `.val()` method, which can both **set** and **get** the value of an `input` element. Read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: thank you works =), why is my js not loading when its at the bottom of the page ?

Comment: @DanielKalenda, no problem. What do you mean?

Comment: i put your code in js tags on the bottom of my html page but it only works when i put it inside my console.

Comment: It would be nicer if you have used the same selectors/tags as the question.

Comment: @DanielKalenda, can you make a jsfiddle, I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: @DanielKalenda, the problem isn't with my code, the problem is with either where you've included other scripts, or the DOM, etc. I'll need to see the structure of your HTML page and JS

Comment: fixed it, sorry had a little typo ;)

Comment: @DanielKalenda, ah okay good, glad it worked! May I suggest marking this answer as accepted in order to close the question?

Answer (score 2):

Text area value can be replaced with val()

```
  $('textarea[name="posting_twitter"]').val(text)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$( 'textarea[name="posting"]' ).on( "keyup", function() {

 var text = $('textarea[name="posting"]').val();
    $('textarea[name="posting_twitter"]').val(text);
      alert(text);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

like this?

html

```
<textarea name = "posting"></textarea>
<textarea name = "posting_twitter"></textarea>
```

jquery

```
$('textarea[name="posting"]').on("keyup", function(){
    var text = $(this).val();
    $('textarea[name="posting_twitter"]').val(text);    
});
```